# 'cassandraCluster' bean exception while starting Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, guava

I am getting the below exception while starting the Spring Boot Application.
Spring Boot Version: 2.1.13
Spring Framework Version: 5.1.14

**Exception:**
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraCluster' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster]: Factory method 'cassandraCluster' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847) ~[spring-beans-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.14.RELEASE.jar:5.1.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.13.RELEASE.jar:2.1.13.RELEASE]

**Caused By:**
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Detected incompatible version of Guava in the classpath. You need 16.0.1 or higher.
    at com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility.selectImplementation(GuavaCompatibility.java:191) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility.(GuavaCompatibility.java:59) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

But I have guava-19.0 version jar in the classpath.

I was not facing this issue with Spring Boot 2.1.6 and Spring Framework 5.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two versions of Guava on your classpath. Some other packages might pull the other version. You should pin the version of Guava inside the `<dependencyManagement>` section of Maven (I expect you use Maven):

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

or exclude the Guava dependency from the other dependency which pulls it too.

Hint for the future: Consider adding the Maven Enforcer Plugin to your project and check for dependency convergence to check for such similar issues:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <DependencyConvergence/>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
...
</build>
```